# Regex to delete all characters after space // Android Java

Tags: java, android, regex

I try to convert following string `1.00 h.` to `1.00` with RegEx but I'm new with it and need your help. I've tried as follows

```
seanceLengthValue = Integer.parseInt(
currentService.getSeanceLength().replaceAll("\\D\\w+",""));
```

Comment: **convert following string "1.00 h." to 1.00 with RegEx** -> Even if you get 1.00, it still wont work. Can't parse `1.00` to int.

Answer (score 1):

Just match/keep/capture the first *non-whitespace characters* and anchor the expression to the start:

```
^(\S+)
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/plCveX/1/) (in `Java` you need to escape the backslashes so it becomes `^(\\S+)` effectively).

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use :

```
seanceLengthValue = Double.parseDouble(
            currentService.getSeanceLength().replaceAll(" [a-zA-Z]", "");
```

Here, we replace all occurrences of alphabets and spaces with `""`. Also, since the resulting string will be a *double*, you need to use `Double.parseDouble()` for conversion.

Answer (score 1):

This is how you can do it

```
String str = "1.00 h";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^(\\S+)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
m.find();
Log.i("Findings", "value is >>" + m.group(0) + "<<");
```

This would give you everything which is before the whitespace.

Now when you are parsing it needs to be parsed in float or double becuase it has a floating point value.

```
seanceLengthValue = Float.parseFloat(m.group(0));
```

**Note:** In case of multiple whitespaces it would still give the first occurrence only.

e.g;  If the string is "1.00 h 2.00 f"; it would give "1.00" only.

Answer (score 0):

Try this pattern: `(\d*\.\d+|\d+)`

It uses alternation to let you match various type of decimal number formats:

`\d*\.\d+` will match zero or more digits `\d`, dot literally `\.` and then one or more digits `\d+`, so it will match 1.0, .01, etc.

`\d+` - matches one or more digits, in case there is decimal separator.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/EKoHgI/2)